# Shift operator in CUDA

Tags: cuda

Given this CUDA code, I am trying to perform bit shifting operations and the return on these values is zero. This should not be happening. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Am I missing a CUDA header include?

**Code**

```
      __device__ unsigned int FI( unsigned int in_data, unsigned int subkey, 
     unsigned int *KLi1, unsigned int *KLi2, unsigned int *KOi1, unsigned int *KOi2,
     unsigned int *KOi3, unsigned int *KIi1, unsigned int *KIi2, unsigned int *KIi3) {

      unsigned int nine, seven;

      unsigned int S7[128]  = {};

      unsigned int S9[512] = {};

      nine = (in_data>>7);
      seven = (in_data&0x7F);

      /* Now run the various operations */
      nine = (unsigned int)(S9[nine] ^ seven);
      seven = (unsigned int)(S7[seven] ^ (nine & 0x7F));
      seven ^= (subkey>>9);
      nine ^= (subkey&0x1FF);
      nine = (unsigned int)(S9[nine] ^ seven);
      seven = (unsigned int)(S7[seven] ^ (nine & 0x7F));
      in_data = (unsigned int)((seven<<9) + nine);
      return( in_data );
      }
```

---

**Breakpoint Analysis**

Here is an example of a code snippet that shifts an unsigned int 7 places to the right. When I cuda-gdb my exec and breakpoint at the instruction, I observe that the value after shifting remains zero when it shouldn't. When I normally execute the same operation in cuda-gdb command prompt, I get a non-zero value. Any suggestions or hints?

The variables nine and seven should be non-empty based on the value of `in_data`.

```
    nine = (in_data>>7);
    seven = (in_data&0x7F);

    [Switching focus to CUDA kernel 0, grid 1, block (0,0,0), thread (1,0,0), device 0, sm 0, warp 0, lane 1]
    Breakpoint 1, FI (KLi1=0x3fffae0, KLi2=0x3fffb00, KOi1=0x3fffb20, KOi2=0x3fffb40, KOi3=0x3fffb60, 
    KIi1=0x3fffb80, KIi2=0x3fffba0, KIi3=0x3fffbc0, in_data=461, subkey=0) at kasumiOp.cu:61
     61   nine = (in_data>>7);
     (cuda-gdb) p in_data
     $1 = 461
     (cuda-gdb) step
     62   seven = (in_data&0x7F);
     (cuda-gdb) p nine
     $2 = 0
     (cuda-gdb) step
     65   nine = (unsigned int)(S9[nine] ^ seven);
     (cuda-gdb) p seven
     $3 = 0
     (cuda-gdb) p 461 >> 7
     $4 = 3
     (cuda-gdb) cuda thread
     thread (1,0,0)
     (cuda-gdb) p 561 & 0x7f
     $5 = 49
     (cuda-gdb) p 461 & 0x7f
     $6 = 77
```

So, `in_data` is a value. I will try a trivial example and see if I can reproduce the same.

Comment: The shift operator in CUDA should work the same way as C. Could you post a minimum sized example reproducing the problem instead of your debugging session? Are you sure that `in_data` actually contains the value you expect?

Comment: Are you debugging a debug build?

Comment: This is not a compilable and executable full code. From the `__device__` function only, we don't not know how `in_data` is set.

Answer (score 1):

With the limited information provided (no code) I might take a guess:

the [CUDA-GDB documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-gdb/) states:

```
The GDB print command has been extended to decipher the location of any program variable and can be used to display the contents of any CUDA program variable including:
* data allocated via cudaMalloc()
* data that resides in various GPU memory regions, such as shared, local, and global memory
* special CUDA runtime variables, such as threadIdx
```

if *in_data* refers to a particular memory area then it might be that you're dealing with memory pointers instead of real data.

Just my two cents though.